# How to change this rare Custom Post Type Archive URL

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I need to change this URL:

```
mysite.com/installation_folder/?post_type=event&when=weekend
```

to

```
mysite.com/installation_folder/whats-happening-this-weekend
```

I tried to use this function but it doesn't work:

```
function my_custom_rewrite_rule() {
  add_rewrite_rule("^installation_folder/whats-happening-this-([^/]+)/?",'index.php?post_type=event&when=$matches[1]','top');
}
add_action('init', 'my_custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

I've flushed everything but nothing work. I have my WP installation under a folder called 'installation_folder', Is that the problem?

Thank you very much for your help!